# Calling page_load of first webform from another webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am opening a second webform on a button click of first webform. On second webform, I perform certain action and store it in a session to use it later. Now after performing certain action on second webform and closing it, I want a post back on first webform. (Note: both webform are independent of each other. No parent child relationship between them). However, I tried calling Page_load of first form from second webform, but failed to do as it's not accepting the arguments of page_load. Neither null arguments are accepted by page_load.
Please help !

Comment: Hi Ptachi. Please show us your code and your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

`Page_Load` is a page lifecycle event which is supposed to get called when the page is loading.

I don't think you will be able to call it from other page's `page_load` event.

**Alternative** is to create a helper class and keep the reusable code there in the separate helper class.

Then both of your web forms can call the helper class method from their page loads.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to use `Server.Execute(string)` which is going to run the other page events including Page_Load and Page_Init, and return the control to the calling page.

```
Server.Execute("mysite.com/page2.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Redirect to go back to the first page - the page will then cycle and go through the Page_Load and do what you need to do.
If you need to tell the other page something then add a URL parameter

eg: `Redirect("~/page1.aspx?reload=1")`